# Is it possible to get the value of angle BAC in this case?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image]

AB (240 m) is a base of an object  that is tilted over the ramp with angle BCE = 45 degrees. CE is 60 m, ie. the known section of the object on the ground say if ramp had not been there.

My aim is to find out the value of BAC, ie the angle at which the object is tilted.

I have tried and could find out the length of various segments. But can't get to any way that can relate it with the angle BAC

Comment: @Vishwas Have you tried to use the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) and/or the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)?

Comment: Hint: You don't need $E$. You have $AB = 240, AC = 180, ACB = 135°$

Comment: For more details on how to apply the laws of sines or cosines, see [solution of triangles on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles#Two_sides_and_non-included_angle_given_(SSA)).

Comment: @Gribouillis I don't want ACB . I want value of BAC.

Comment: @peterwhy I know the formulae quite well. But this one proved to be difficult to sort out.

Comment: $AB=AE=b, CE=a$ and $\angle{BCE}=45^{\circ}$ implies $BE=CE$ so you have, calling $\angle{BAC}=\theta$
$$\cos(\theta)=1-\dfrac{a^2}{2b^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

By the law of cosines$$AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-2AC\cdot BC\cos135^o$$So$$BC^2=AB^2-AC^2+2AC\cdot BC\cos135^o$$or$$BC^2=240^2-180^2-1.414\cdot 180BC$$i.e.$$BC^2=25200-254.52BC$$and$$BC^2+254.52BC-25200=0$$By the quadratic formula:$$BC=\frac{-254.52+\sqrt{254.52^2-4\cdot 25200}}{2}$$and$$BC\approx 76.2$$Again by the cosine law$$\cos \angle BAC=\frac{AB^2+AC^2-BC^2}{2AB\cdot AC}\approx .97$$and hence$$\angle BAC\approx 12.95^o$$