# If length AB, $(x_1,y_1)$ angle POQ are given. Is it possible to get point B $(x_2,y_2)$ ? Yes or No ? Or is the information insufficient?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

This is a modification of my previous question here:
[Is it possible to get the value of angle BAC in this case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740753/is-it-possible-to-get-the-value-of-angle-bac-in-this-case?noredirect=1#comment10054164_4740753)

[image]

If length AB (say $100$m), $(x_1,y_1)$ say $(-50,0)$ and angle POQ ($30$ degrees) are given. Is it possible to get $(x_2,y_2)$ ? Yes or No ? Or the information still is insufficient to calculate $x_2$ and $y_2$ ?

I can do all sines and cosines myself. But only need some hints.

Comment: Hint: if you can find $\overline{\rm OB}$, you can find $x_2$ and $y_2$.

Use law of cosines for  $\overline{\rm AB}$,  $\overline{\rm AO}$ and $\angle BOA$ to find  $\overline{\rm OB}$

Comment: Law of cosines for AB, AO and ∠BOA ? But where is the 90 degree triangle in this case through which I can use sines/cosines? 
To find OB, I will draw a perpendicular from B to x-axis. Say it's point 'S'. But what is the value of  OS ? Because the only thing I know in the triangle BOS is the angle POQ = 30 degrees. And that is not sufficient information to use sines and cosines to get the value of the sides of triangle.

Comment: I edited my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $BC \perp x-axis$ and $BC=x$ then $OC=x\sqrt3$

$x^2+(x\sqrt3 + 50)^2=100^2$

$x^2+25\sqrt3 x-1875=0$

$x=\frac{-25\sqrt3+25\sqrt{15} }{2}$ or $x=26.76$

then

$x_2=x\sqrt3=\frac{-75+75\sqrt{5} }{2}$ or $x_2=46.35$

$y_2=x=\frac{-25\sqrt3+25\sqrt{15} }{2}$ or $y_2=x=26.76$

Comment: Correct. Only thing is that the result of your calculations for the quadratic equation is wrong. x comes approximately 28 .  And thank you for the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The information is sufficient.

Draw a circle with centre (x1, y1) and form a locus of its circumference when radius is 100m.

Using point-slope form you can form the equation for the line PO.

Now based on (x1, y1) you can have one or two coordinates possible for B.